# Catching Same Exception between Methods/ Classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I'm calling a function to get data from types of source, so I created a superclass called `FileReader` and several classes, each for FTP, SFTP, Google Drive etc.. Each of them will inherit and implement a `get_data` function.

I want to catch the exceptions returned by gems so that we don't report the outside factors as a bug report to Rollbar, so we rescue the exceptions and return proper message to the users when the file is not found, request timed out etc. Rescue block is on superclass because exceptions like SocketError, EOFError is common on all subclasses so I'm trying to keep my code dry.

```
class FileReader

  def get_data
    nil
  end

  def read
    data = nil
    begin
      data = get_data
    rescue EOFError => e
      # return error message
    rescue SocketError => e
      # return error message
    rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e
      # return error message
    rescue Net::FTPPermError => e
      # return error message
    rescue Net::SFTP::StatusException => e
      # return error message
    rescue Errno::ETIMEDOUT => e
      # return error message
    rescue Exception => e
      puts e.message
      puts e.backtrace.join("\n")
      Rollbar.error(e, :source => self)
      # return error message
    end
    return data
  end

end
```

FtpFileReader inherits FileReader class to implement the `get_data` function.

```
class FtpFileReader < FileReader

  def get_data
    # connect to ftp, get file, return data
    # no begin and rescue block here
  end

end
```

and my `read` method is called from my Rails model.

But catching such exceptions are tricky to me.
The calling method `read` is catching this exception, do `FileReader#get_data` method catches the same exception too if I implement a rescue block in it?

Should I catch these exceptions in FileReader `get_data` method instead of `read`? Or should I catch these specific exceptions in subclasses itself and return the error message in each `get_data` method in subclass? Eventually the classes to catch will be bigger but duplicating EOFError, SocketError is not so dry. What will be the best way of handling exceptions in cases like this?

Comment: Why do you think that error should be caught by one of your clauses (other than the catch all rescue Exception clause)

Comment: @FrederickCheung what do you mean?

Comment: I mean why do you think that error shouldn't end up in the `rescue Exception` bit?

Comment: you got Net::FTPTempError not Net::FTPPermError. You don't handle Net::FTPTempError like other special cases, it is handled in `rescue Exception => e`

Comment: @FrederickCheung To catch different types of error message to users so that they know what's the problem when they want to get the data, for example FTP authentication fail, file not found etc. The generic Exception rescue bit is to catch the potential bugs such as NilClass error.

Comment: @YuriyGolobokov oh good catch. Will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, never rescue from `Exception` (unless you are re-raising, and even then, ask yourself why you are doing it). Rescue from `StandardError` instead. Read about it [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rescue-standarderror-not-exception).

I would define `rescue`s for subclass-specific errors only in those subclasses so that that specific logic can be completely isolated to the subclass in question. You can do this as you suggested, by moving the specific error catching to the `get_data` method. But you might consider defining a new method so you can use the non-rescuing method (maybe just for debugging purposes, or from another controller where you want to handle errors differently). Here's one way I'd consider doing that:

```
class FtpFileReader < FileReader
  def get_data
    get_data!
  rescue Net::FTPPermErro => e
    # return error message
  end

  def get_data!
    # do stuff
  end
end
```